# Forming timedeltas for segments of rows, where each segment starts and ends with a matching value but has nulls in between

Tags: sql, time-series, amazon-athena, presto, timedelta

I have a table with the following relevant columns:

- PK
- username
- task
- timestamp

This is essentially time series data. Sometimes, we don't capture the task ID, but we know that null values between matching task IDs are actually part of a segment.

I think of these segments as having a head with a task ID, a body of null values, and a tail with a matching task ID. An alternative way of thinking of these segments is as a parenthetical: there are opening and closing brackets (with task IDs) and between the two are null values.

**Goal:** I'd like to get all of the time deltas for these segments. I'm ultimately hoping to plot a distribution of these time deltas since I'm interested in how long these gaps in captured task ID can be.

---

I can transform the data like the following:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        t.username,
        t.timestamp,
        t.task,
        lag(t.task, 1) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY t.username ORDER BY t.timestamp) AS PRE,
        lead(t.task, 1) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY t.username ORDER BY t.timestamp) AS POST
    FROM
        "dbschema"."dbtable" t
    where
        t.username = 'johnasdough'
)
```

Here is an excerpt of that output:

```
PK   USERNAME       TIMESTAMP                  TASK         PRE          POST
11   johnasdough    2023-05-25 14:45:02.990    de2a2b65     de2a2b65    de2a2b65
12   johnasdough    2023-05-25 14:45:04.680    null         de2a2b65    de2a2b65
13   johnasdough    2023-05-25 14:45:08.492    null         de2a2b65    de2a2b65
14   johnasdough    2023-05-25 14:45:11.588    de2a2b65     de2a2b65    de2a2b65
15   johnasdough    2023-05-25 14:45:38.289    8dfbf2cc     8dfbf2cc    8dfbf2cc
16   johnasdough    2023-05-25 14:45:40.276    null         8dfbf2cc    8dfbf2cc
17   johnasdough    2023-05-25 14:45:41.559    null         8dfbf2cc    8dfbf2cc
18   johnasdough    2023-05-25 14:45:45.117    null         8dfbf2cc    8dfbf2cc
19   johnasdough    2023-05-25 14:45:45.305    8dfbf2cc     8dfbf2cc    8dfbf2cc
```

**Question:** how can I use SQL to get the time delta between the start and stop of segments? That is, I wish to find the duration of segments where TASK is the same as PRE and POST for the first and last rows with nulls in between.

For example:

```
USERNAME       ID_START    ID_STOP    TASK         TIMEDELTA
johnasdough    11          14         de2a2b65    (some time in milliseconds)
johnasdough    15          19         8dfbf2cc    (some time in milliseconds)
```

Note that I am not interested in the time delta for successively captured task IDs; there must be at least one null task IDs between two matching captured ones.

---

- Data size: hundreds of millions of records
- Technology: AWS Athena (Presto)

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this with your query made into a CTE, just subtract the next timestamp when the task equals the pre or post column you've created and also `partition by` the task

```
with tbl as (SELECT
        t.username,
        t.timestamp,
        t.task,
        lag(t.task, 1) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY t.username ORDER BY t.timestamp) AS PRE,
        lead(t.task, 1) IGNORE NULLS OVER (PARTITION BY t.username ORDER BY t.timestamp) AS POST
    FROM
        "dbschema"."dbtable" t
    where
        t.username = 'johnasdough'
) select *, tbl.t.timestamp - lag(tbl.t.timestamp,1)
  over(partition by tbl.t.task) as timediff
  from tbl where tbl.t.task = tbl.pre;
```